# AngularJs SPA Javascript file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, authentication, single-page-application

Do i have to include all my javascript file while loading main index page?

In single page application when we are not logged in, we include all of our .js file in main index file. This contains js file that is only needed when users are logged in.

What is better approach of managing angular app in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: yes.

Your application is a single-page one, so you can combine all JS files into one and load it at one request. It saves time for processing in the future.

Alternatively, create two pages `login.html` and `others.html`, then load two different sets of JS files accordingly.

Normally, nowadays the bandwidth is not the bottleneck, loading a larger JS file does not make trouble (usually).

Answer (score 0):

You can split your code into multiple modules and then just load the js needed for that module.

I suggest using Gulp with packages to inject HTML when appropriate. You then have single lines of code as place holders for your Javascript and you run the Gulp task to inject the Javascript into the areas where it is needed.

You could also run gulp tasks to minify your js into just a few minified files. You will need to be sure your js in min safe (gulp can do this too).

Answer (score 0):

If you make AMD - most often using RequireJS - then you won't need to include all from the very beginning.

A while ago we did a similar project, although without AngularJS, and by using RequireJS we made the different pages, which use different files. And this way people's browsers will never download certain files if they never go to certain pages.

(Of course, we had many pages inside the app, not just 2 or 3, where this wouldn't make any difference.)